# react-pdf onItemClick is not working

Tags: reactjs, pdf.js, react-pdf

I am using react-pdf to show the pdf document. left i am showing pages preview when we click on the page i am showing the page content in the seperate section. For that i am using onItemClick event. But which is not getting triggered.

Below is the code sample

```
onPageClick = ({ pageNumber }) => {
    alert('Clicked an item from page ' + pageNumber + '!')
}

 let display = [1,2,3,4,5].map((page, index) => {
        return (<Page key={index} onItemClick={this.onPageClick} pageNumber={index + 1} scale={1.0} width={100} />)
    });

<Document  file={this.state.fileDatapdf}               

           > {display}</Document>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below is the solution which i got finally.

I have put one div in between document and page and added click event to the div.

```
   <Document    file={file}
                                            loader={loader}
                                            onItemClick={this.onPageClick}
                                            onLoadSuccess={this.onDocumentLoad}>
                                            <div className='highlighed-pdf'>
                                                <Page onItemClick={this.onPageClick} pageNumber={this.state.openedPageNo} scale={2} width={480} />
                                            </div>
                                        </Document>
```

Hope this will help one or other :)

This is the github issue tracker.

[enter link description here](https://github.com/wojtekmaj/react-pdf/issues/187)

still it is open